# How to create script to access email and display in browser

Tags: python, email, email-verification

I am trying to create a Python script that allows me to log into my email with my password and username and then opens a browser that logs in using that information so I don't need to enter my info. So far this is what I have:

```
os.system("start chrome.exe http://www.yahoomail.com")
```

This allows me to start chrome to that url which obviously just opens it and doesn't log me in automatically. So I want to know how can I make it so that it opens a browser and logs into my email automatically?
Thanks to whoever answers.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium), that's exactly what you are looking for. Also as an option you can use some headless broser like `PhantomJS` or you can use `PyQt4 (Webkit)`.

Comment: What do you mean by adding functionality? Is it possible to use Selenium and, say, PyQT4 Webkit at the same time?

Comment: You can but, what's the point of it?

Comment: Exactly. What do you mean by "add little more functionality?"

Comment: Got you, I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

The [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) library seems to be able to handle logins (sometimes the help of a cookie manager like [cookielib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html) is also needed.)  The catch is that each e-mail service will be a bit different and you have to go digging through the source code for that page (Ctrl+U in several browsers like Firefox and Google Chrome) to look for the names it uses for the various variables.  The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925983/login-to-website-using-urllib2-python-2-7) should provide a good idea of how to go about this.