# How do I use Python to Login to a website using urllib2 and then open a browser page to the logged in site?

Tags: python, authentication, urllib2

I saw a similar question asking for help logging into reddit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925983/login-to-website-using-urllib2-python-2-7).

The site I want to login seems more complex.  The form from the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="bottom-wrapper">

    <div class="sidebar-container">

        <div id="logged-in-user">

            <div class="ajax-loading"></div>

            <div class="panel-pane pane-type1 anonymous-content" id="pane-login-block">

                <h2 class="pane-title">Login</h2>

                <div id="login-section" class="pane-content">



                    <form method="post" action="https://www.fancywebsite.com/php/login.php">

                        <input type="hidden" name="destination" value="">

                        <input type="hidden" value="user_login" name="form_id">

                        <input type="hidden" value="2800" name="affid">

                        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="blocklogin">

                        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="wager">

                        <input id="edit-redirect" type="hidden" value="http://www.fancywebsite.com/main" name="redirect">



                        <ul class="field-set">

                            <li>

                                <label for="username">Username:</label>

                                <input type="text" name="acct" id="username" class="text-box" maxlength="100" size="20">

                            </li>

                            <li>

                                <label for="password">Password:</label>

                                <input type="password" name="pin" id="password" class="text-box" maxlength="16" size="20">

                            </li>

                            <li>

                                <span id="reset-login-link"><a href="https://www.fancywebsite.com/account/password/request">forgot your login information?</a></span>

                                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" id="Login" name="Login">

                            </li>

                        </ul>



                    </form>
```

I want Python to go to that login page and enter my credentials and then open a browser to the logged in page.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I tried to adapt the method from the reddit example work, without luck.  I don't want to use mechanize.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide code that you have tried. Also it would be much easier of you would provide the actual website that you want to log in. Or provide POST data that web browser sends when you log in

Comment: the website is twinspires.com.  I want to download present toteboard odds.  I tried the code I cited in the link above.  I will try to find out how to post POST data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either requests and urllib2 to login or you can use mechanize to simulate the browser, which is a better way I think.
Here is link you can refer to:
[requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage) or [mechanize](http://stockrt.github.io/p/emulating-a-browser-in-python-with-mechanize/)

Comment: My Python can't use requests or mechanize.  The reddit link shown above suggests neither is required.

Comment: Thanks fyr0049 - I broke down and loaded a version of Python that incorporates mechanize and requests...works great.