# How to scrape a website which requires login using python and beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

If I want to scrape a website that requires login with password first, how can I start scraping it with python using beautifulsoup4 library? Below is what I do for websites that do not require login.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
import urllib2 
url = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.python.org")    
content = url.read()    
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
```

How should the code be changed to accommodate login? Assume that the website I want to scrape is a forum that requires login. An example is http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use mechanize:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 
import cookielib ## http.cookiejar in python3

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("https://id.arduino.cc/auth/login/")

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['username'] = 'username'
br.form['password'] = 'password.'
br.submit()

print br.response().read()
```

Or urllib - [Login to website using urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925983/login-to-website-using-urllib2-python-2-7)

Comment: 'br.form['username'] = 'username'


is the first 'username' the name of the form and the second one the actual username?

Comment: @DanS. This is quite late.. but for anyone else seeing this, yes.. the first username is the form field name.. and the second username would be the actual username that you'd enter into that form field.

Comment: This answer is right for Python 2, for Python 3 I'll recommend using mechanicalsoup https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @JérômeB That's quite an unhelpful comment, given that you haven't contributed an answer here. I presume you are referring to this page https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html?highlight=login#a-more-complete-example-logging-in-into-github ...

Comment: `urllib2` for Python3 should be `urllib` https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html?highlight=urllib2

Answer (score 60):

There is a simpler way, from my pov, that gets you there without `selenium` or `mechanize`, or other 3rd party tools, albeit it is *semi*-automated.

Basically, when you login into a site in a normal way, you identify yourself in a unique way using your credentials, and the same identity is used  thereafter for every other interaction, which is stored in `cookies` and `headers`, for a brief period of time.

What you need to do is use the same `cookies` and `headers` when you make your http requests, and you'll be in.

To replicate that, follow these steps:

1. In your browser, open the developer tools
2. Go to the site, and login
3. **After** the login, go to the network tab, and **then** **refresh** the page
   At this point, you should see a list of requests, the top one being the actual site - and that will be our focus, because it contains the data with the identity we can use for Python and BeautifulSoup to scrape it
4. Right click the site request (the top one), hover over `copy`, and then `copy as  cURL`
   Like this:

[image]

5. Then go to this site which converts cURL into python requests: https://curlconverter.com/
6. Take the python code and use the generated `cookies` and `headers` to proceed with the scraping

Comment: thank you so much for this answer! I using it currently to scrape a website for apartment rents. Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure how to quickly apply this technique of scraping. Therefore, I asked a question about it. Do you have any ideas on it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67125550/how-does-one-scrape-multiple-pages-with-beautiful-soup-for-a-website-that-requir

Comment: Thank you for the great tip. Step 3 may vary if the login page request is redirected (status code 30x). In this case, it is too late to see the Network tab after login. I would recommend instead: a) get address (URL) from the `action` attribute of the login `<form>` and replace it in cURL, or b) open the Network tab; wait until the login page and all resources are loaded; fill in the login form; clear the Network tab; submit login form -> then the first request in the Network tab would contain the required address (URL).

Comment: This works great for places which require a captcha in the login page; for these, mechanicalsoup doesn't work.

Comment: This works, but I have to login and copy the curl every time I want to run the script?
After logging out/closing the tab I get a 'TooManyRedirects' Error when running my code.

Comment: @SYNEC either that or, depending on what access you have on the site you want to scrape, you authenticate another way - the key is you have to authenticate and get the proper header information to be able to retrieve the data programatically, and this curl method eases that part a bit

Comment: On my version of devtools I have `Copy as cURL (cmd)` and `Copy as cURL (bash)`, the one that worked was `bash`

Comment: question: after two days I had to generate new cookies and headers. How Can I make sure that I dont need to renw the cookie?

Comment: That is why I said it’s semi-automated. Those expire, and the expiry date is controlled by the server

Answer (score 11):

If you go for selenium, then you can do something like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# If you want to open Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# If you want to open Firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
username.send_keys("YourUsername")
password.send_keys("YourPassword")
driver.find_element_by_id("submit_btn").click()
```

However, if you're adamant that you're only going to use BeautifulSoup, you can do that with a library like `requests` or `urllib`. Basically all you have to do is `POST` the data as a payload with the URL.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login_url = 'http://example.com/login'
data = {
    'username': 'your_username',
    'password': 'your_password'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.post(login_url , data)
    print(response.text)
    index_page= s.get('http://example.com')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(index_page.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.title)
```

Comment: Regarding using `requests`, you will want to do `s.post(login_url, data)` not `requests.post(login_url, data)` or you lose the benefits of using the same session for subsequent requests. Otherwise, you probably won't be logged into the website on the next `get` page request. This is especially useful when you have a site that is not even using a form but just input elements and a button tied to javascript making an AJAX xmlHttpRequest to a different URL (basically a rest API to login) where MechanicalSoup won't work well.

Answer (score 7):

You can use selenium to log in and retrieve the page source, which you can then pass to Beautiful Soup to extract the data you want.

Comment: Consider providing more details in your answer.

Comment: what is the advantage when using selenium?

Answer (score 7):

Since Python version wasn't specified, [here is my take on it for Python 3, done without any external libraries (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61213103/13312932). After login use BeautifulSoup as usual, or any other kind of scraping.

Likewise, [script on my GitHub here](https://github.com/luxzg/Python3/commit/68b780e3ab1402be9e37a8a3f6d06bcea4b6732a#diff-0680ac0627f7a09dfac8ce2d1eed06be)

Whole script replicated below as to StackOverflow guidelines:

```
# Login to website using just Python 3 Standard Library
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import http.cookiejar

def scraper_login():
    ####### change variables here, like URL, action URL, user, pass
    # your base URL here, will be used for headers and such, with and without https://
    base_url = 'www.example.com'
    https_base_url = 'https://' + base_url

    # here goes URL that's found inside form action='.....'
    #   adjust as needed, can be all kinds of weird stuff
    authentication_url = https_base_url + '/login'

    # username and password for login
    username = 'yourusername'
    password = 'SoMePassw0rd!'

    # we will use this string to confirm a login at end
    check_string = 'Logout'

    ####### rest of the script is logic
    # but you will need to tweak couple things maybe regarding "token" logic
    #   (can be _token or token or _token_ or secret ... etc)

    # big thing! you need a referer for most pages! and correct headers are the key
    headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/81.0.4044.92",    # Chrome 80+ as per web search
    "Host":base_url,
    "Origin":https_base_url,
    "Referer":https_base_url}

    # initiate the cookie jar (using : http.cookiejar and urllib.request)
    cookie_jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

    # first a simple request, just to get login page and parse out the token
    #       (using : urllib.request)
    request = urllib.request.Request(https_base_url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    contents = response.read()

    # parse the page, we look for token eg. on my page it was something like this:
    #    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="random1234567890qwertzstring">
    #       this can probably be done better with regex and similar
    #       but I'm newb, so bear with me
    html = contents.decode("utf-8")
    # text just before start and just after end of your token string
    mark_start = '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'
    mark_end = '">'
    # index of those two points
    start_index = html.find(mark_start) + len(mark_start)
    end_index = html.find(mark_end, start_index)
    # and text between them is our token, store it for second step of actual login
    token = html[start_index:end_index]

    # here we craft our payload, it's all the form fields, including HIDDEN fields!
    #   that includes token we scraped earler, as that's usually in hidden fields
    #   make sure left side is from "name" attributes of the form,
    #       and right side is what you want to post as "value"
    #   and for hidden fields make sure you replicate the expected answer,
    #       eg. "token" or "yes I agree" checkboxes and such
    payload = {
        '_token':token,
    #    'name':'value',    # make sure this is the format of all additional fields !
        'login':username,
        'password':password
    }

    # now we prepare all we need for login
    #   data - with our payload (user/pass/token) urlencoded and encoded as bytes
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
    binary_data = data.encode('UTF-8')
    # and put the URL + encoded data + correct headers into our POST request
    #   btw, despite what I thought it is automatically treated as POST
    #   I guess because of byte encoded data field you don't need to say it like this:
    #       urllib.request.Request(authentication_url, binary_data, headers, method='POST')
    request = urllib.request.Request(authentication_url, binary_data, headers)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    contents = response.read()

    # just for kicks, we confirm some element in the page that's secure behind the login
    #   we use a particular string we know only occurs after login,
    #   like "logout" or "welcome" or "member", etc. I found "Logout" is pretty safe so far
    contents = contents.decode("utf-8")
    index = contents.find(check_string)
    # if we find it
    if index != -1:
        print(f"We found '{check_string}' at index position : {index}")
    else:
        print(f"String '{check_string}' was not found! Maybe we did not login ?!")

scraper_login()
```