# How do I Login to A site using Python for scraping purposes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm relatively new to python and programming generally. I've tried to follow steps provided from similar questions here but My program is unable to successfully Log in. The latest code I got from [How to scrape a website which requires login using python and beautifulsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102833/how-to-scrape-a-website-which-requires-login-using-python-and-beautifulsoup/23103784#)
Below is my attempted code: and the response I get

```
import mechanize
import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 
import cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("http://www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2/?do=signin&service=prepaidsms&returnto=http%3A%2F%2Fsms.bbnplace.com%2Fsentdir.php")

br.select_form('blogin')
br.form['busername'] = 'my_username'
br.form['passwd'] = 'my_password'
response = br.submit()

print br.response().read()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="keywords" content="bulksms, bulk sms, bulk sms gateway, cheap bulk sms, bulk sms provider, bulk sms to nigeria, send bulk sms, personalized bulk sms, bulk sms nigeria, best sms site in nigeria, nigerian bulks sms gateway, web to mobile sms" />
<meta http-equiv="description" content="Send bulk sms with personalized sender name to all GSM networks in Nigeria and over 800 networks in 160 countries. Nigeria's Best SMS Gateway." />
<title>BBN SMS Messenger: Retail Web to Mobile Bulk SMS Messaging Utility</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2/style/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" async src="http://www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2/bbjs/un.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var L;var C;var bw=0;var G;var eD;var am;var eE=0;var method;var url;var J;var be;var fp='';var eY='';var dW=0;var eH='dG';var eG;var action='sent';var bS=0;var eC='';var eW=new Number();var bP='';var ft='save';var host=document.domain=='localhost'?'localhost/smsmessenger/':'sms.bbnplace.com';var protocol='http';var fc;var eA=protocol+"://"+host+"/source/";var dR=0;var responseText;var response=new Array();var bs;var bV=new Number();var H;var request;var fl;var aB;var aQ;var aL=window.innerWidth;var ab=window.innerHeight;var ca=new Array();var aK=new Array();var cv=new Array();var bb=new Array();var dN=new Array();aB=document.getElementById('aD');var et=110;aQ=document.getElementById('bx');if(request=='gocheck'){ad();}function ak(v){var k=document.getElementById(v);k.style.visibility='hidden';k.style.height='0px';};function aE(v){var k=document.getElementById(v);k.style.visibility='inherit';k.style.height='auto';};function bJ(v,ba){var ids=new Array();var aw=new String();aw=ba;ids=aw.split(',');for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){ak(ids[i]);}ids='';aE(v);return;};function ay(bF,cF,dw,bH,bi,aq,bN,aA){be=bi;C=bH;G=aq;H=aA;J=dw;method=bF;url=cF;am=bN;L=bO();if(L){if(method=='post'){try{L.open(method,url,true);L.onreadystatechange=bg;L.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');L.setRequestHeader('Content-Length',J.length);L.setRequestHeader('Connection','close');L.send(J);}catch(e){alert("Error connecting to server: "+e.toString());}}else{try{J.length>1?aG=url+'?'+J:aG=url;L.open(method,aG,true);L.onreadystatechange=bg;L.send(null);}catch(e){alert("Could not connect to server: "+e.toString());}}}};function bg(){var d;if(C.length>0){d=document.getElementById(C);}if(L.readyState==4){if(L.status==200){try{var response=dO();if(C.length>0){d.style.visibility='hidden';}bw=0;}catch(e){d.innerHTML="Error reading server response: "+e.toString();}}else{if(C.length>0){if(L.status){d.innerHTML='Server Response: '+L.status+' - '+L.statusText;d.style.visibility='visible';}else{d.innerHTML='Connection to server failed. Retrying...';d.style.visibility='visible';bQ=setTimeout('bz()',5000);}}}}else{if(C.length>0){d.innerHTML='<img border="0" src="style/29.gif" align="absmiddle" /> <b>Loading...</b>';d.style.visibility='visible';ap=setTimeout('dK()',(be*1000));}}return response;};function dK(){if(L.readyState!=4){clearTimeout(ap);document.getElementById(C).innerHTML='Connection is too slow. Retrying...';bQ=setTimeout('bD()',5000);}};function bD(){clearTimeout(bQ);if(L.readyState!=4){L.abort();ay(method,url,J,C,be,G,H);}};function bz(){clearTimeout(bQ);if(!L.status){L.abort();ay(method,url,J,C,be,G,H);}};function df(){x=document.getElementById(C);x.style.visibility='hidden';};function dO(){var responseText,cp;var doctype=L.getResponseHeader('Content-Type').toString();var l=document.getElementById(G);if(H.length){var aJ=document.getElementById(H);}l.innerHTML='';response['type']=doctype;if(doctype=='text/plain'||doctype=='text/html'){responseText=L.responseText;if(responseText.substr(0,4)=='Err:'){l.innerHTML=responseText.substr(5);l.style.visibility='inherit';l.style.height='auto';if(responseText.substr(5)==''){if(bS>0){l.innerHTML='<span style="color:red;">'+bP+'</span>';}}}else if(responseText.substr(0,3)=='OK:'){var aH=responseText.substr(4);switch(request){case 'newpost':document.forms[request].es.value=aH;bs.innerHTML='Saved';eu();break;}}else{if(H.length){aJ.innerHTML=responseText;}else if(request=='gocheck'){l.innerHTML=responseText;y=document.forms.di;if(responseText=='available'){y.cf.value=1;y.ds.value=y.username.value;l.innerHTML='Available';l.style.fontWeight='bold';l.style.color='green';ad();}}else{if(responseText=='successful'){switch(request){case 'newRequest':bJ('h','h,j');break;}}else if(responseText=='denied'){bf=protocol+'://'+host+'/accounts';window.location=bf;}else{alert(responseText);}}}}};function bO(){try{L=new XMLHttpRequest();}catch(e){var aI=new Array('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0','MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0','MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0','MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0','MSXML2.XMLHTTP','Microsoft.XMLHTTP');for(var i=0;i<aI.length&& !L;i++){try{L=new ActiveXObject(aI[i]);}catch(e){}}}if(!L){alert('Please Upgrade your web browser');}else{return L;}};function aN(){var x=document.forms['t'];request='newRequest';aq='V';var bp,ao,aW,az;bp=x.ag.value;ao=x.bI.value;aW=x.aR.value;dr=x.an.value;az=x.av.value;aZ='eml='+encodeURIComponent(ao)+'&f='+encodeURIComponent(bp)+'&p='+encodeURIComponent(aW)+'&m='+encodeURIComponent(az)+'&p2='+encodeURIComponent(dr);al=document.getElementById('V');al.style.visibility='hidden';al.style.height=0;dP='source/contact.php';ay('post',dP,aZ,'',30,'V','','');};function cu(){dJ();};function cl(){ce();};function bB(aX){var x=document.getElementById('bh');if(!x){var x=document.createElement('div');x.setAttribute('id','bh');x.style.backgroundColor='#000';x.style.top='0px';x.style.left='0px';x.style.position='fixed';x.style.zIndex=99999;x.style.opacity=0.5;}x.style.width=aL+'px';x.style.height=ab+'px';x.style.visibility='visible';document.body.appendChild(x);if(aX==null){var T=document.getElementById('t');T.style.visibility='visible';T.style.height='auto';T.style.position='fixed';T.style.left=(aL/2-250)+'px';T.style.width='500px';T.style.zIndex=10000001;bJ('j','h,j');}else{var T=document.getElementById('ax');T.style.visibility='visible';bV=aX;}};function ar(){var bE=document.getElementById('bh');bE.style.width='0px';bE.style.height='0px';bE.style.visibility='hidden';if(bV==0){ak('h');ak('j');ak('t');document.forms['t'].reset();}else{var T=document.getElementById('ax');T.style.visibility='hidden';bV=0;}};function cU(i){var aY=document.getElementById('bA');aY.innerHTML='<b>Message:</b><br />'+aK[i];aY.innerHTML+='<br /><br /><b>Broadcasted:</b> '+bb[i];document.getElementById('as').style.visibility='visible';ez(ca[i]);};function dA(){document.getElementById('as').style.visibility='hidden';document.getElementById('ae').innerHTML='';}</script>
</head>

<body><div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=174240488183";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><div id="ppbd"></div><div id="ppbdc"></div><div id="logoholder"></div>
<div id="app_header">
<div id="line1_left"><img src="http://www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2/style/smlogo.png" align="absmiddle" title="BBN SMS Messenger: Retail Web to Mobile Bulk SMS Messaging Utility" /></div>
  <div id="line1_right"><a href="#">Hi Buddie!</a> | <a href="http://sms.bbnplace.com">Messaging Solutions</a> | <a href="http://www.bbnplace.com">BBN</a> &nbsp; </div>
</div>
<div id="cK" align="right">&nbsp;</div><div id="workarea" align="center">
<div id="frm_right">
        <div id="note_panel"><div align="left">

        <!-- <div style="margin: 0 0 40px; font-size: 22px; line-height: 27px;">
                manage your contacts &bull; send sms to <b style="color: red;">groups</b>
                &bull; from personal computer and <b style="color: red;">mobile</b>
        </div> -->
        <div style="font-size: 28px; line-height: 35px; margin: 35px 0 0;">
                Send bulk sms &bull; <b style="color: red;">confidently!</b>
        </div>
        <div id="bslogin_nav">
                <img alt="How to Recharge" src="style/cc_icon.png" align="absmiddle" />
                <b><a href="#how_to_recharge">Learn How to Recharge</a></b> &nbsp; <img
                        alt="Bundles and Pricing" align="absmiddle" src="style/cog_icon.png" />
                <b><a
                        href="http://www.bbnplace.com/documentation/?service=prepaidsms&article=networks&returnto="
                        target="_blank">See our Network Coverage</a></b>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">function dJ(){var x=document.forms['aN'];var V=new Number(x.df.value);var v=new Number(0);if(isNaN(V)){document.getElementById("J").innerHTML="<span style='color: red;'>waiting...</span>";document.getElementById("hBp").innerHTML="<span style='color: red;'>waiting...</span>";document.getElementById("T").innerHTML="<span style='color: red;'>waiting...</span>";if(document.forms.F){document.forms.F.bJ.disabled=true;}if(document.getElementById("statMsg")){document.getElementById("statMsg").innerHTML="<span style='color: red;'><strong>Please Enter a Numberic Value</strong></span>";}}if(V<50){document.getElementById("J").innerHTML="<span style='color: red;'>waiting...</span>";document.getElementById("hBp").innerHTML="<span style='color: red;'>waiting...</span>";document.getElementById("T").innerHTML="<span style='color: red;'>waiting...</span>";if(document.forms.F){document.forms.F.bJ.disabled=true;}if(document.getElementById("statMsg")){document.getElementById("statMsg").innerHTML="<span style='color: red;'><strong>Please specify a minimum of 50</strong></span>";}}else if(V>=50&&V< 1000){document.getElementById("J").innerHTML="Teams & Groups";document.getElementById("hBp").innerHTML="NGN 3.50";v=V* 3.50;v=v.toFixed(2);document.getElementById("T").innerHTML='NGN '+v;if(document.forms.F){document.forms.F.bJ.disabled=false;}if(document.getElementById("statMsg")){document.getElementById("statMsg").innerHTML='';}if(document.forms.F){document.forms.F.J.value='Teams & Groups';document.forms.F.hBp.value= 3.50;document.forms.F.T.value=v;}}else if(V>= 1000 &&V< 10000){document.getElementById("J").innerHTML="Business Standard";document.getElementById("hBp").innerHTML="NGN 2.20";v=V* 2.20;v=v.toFixed(2);document.getElementById("T").innerHTML='NGN '+v;if(document.forms.F){document.forms.F.bJ.disabled=false;}if(document.getElementById("statMsg")){document.getElementById("statMsg").innerHTML='';}if(document.forms.F){document.forms.F.J.value='Business Standard';document.forms.F.hBp.value= 2.20;document.forms.F.T.value=v;}}else if(V>= 10000 &&V< 50000){document.getElementById("J").innerHTML="Business Professional";document.getElementById("hBp").innerHTML="NGN 2.00";v=V* 2.00;v=v.toFixed(2);document.getElementById("T").innerHTML='NGN '+v;if(document.forms.F){document.forms.F.bJ.disabled=false;}if(document.getElementById("statMsg")){document.getElementById("statMsg").innerHTML='';}if(document.forms.F){document.forms.F.J.value='Business Professional';document.forms.F.hBp.value= 2.00;document.forms.F.T.value=v;}}else if(V>= 50000){document.getElementById("J").innerHTML="Business Premium";document.getElementById("hBp").innerHTML="NGN 1.85";v=V* 1.85;v=v.toFixed(2);document.getElementById("T").innerHTML='NGN '+v;if(document.forms.F){document.forms.F.bJ.disabled=false;}if(document.getElementById("statMsg")){document.getElementById("statMsg").innerHTML='';}if(document.forms.F){document.forms.F.J.value='Business Premium';document.forms.F.hBp.value= 1.85;document.forms.F.T.value=v;}}} </script>
<div align="left" id="pricelist">
        <div align="right"><div id="price_tag"><img src="http://www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2/style/price_tag.png" align="top" /> Bundles &amp; Pricing</div></div>

        <form id="aN" name="aN" method="post" action="">
                <div style="margin: 0 0 5px;">
                <label for="select"></label> <b>Currency</b> <select
                        name="aD" id="aD" onchange="ck(this.value)" disabled="disabled">
                        <option value="ngn"                             selected="selected" >NGN</option>
                        <option value="usd" >USD</option>
                        <option value="eur" >EUR</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="price_tags">
                                <tr>
                                        <th align="left">Bundle</th>
                                        <th width="120" align="right">Min. Volume</th>
                                        <th width="80" align="right">Unit Price</th>
                                </tr>  <tr>
                                        <td style="background-color: #FFF; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: clip;">Teams & Groups</td>
                                        <td align="right" style="background-color: #FFF;">50</td>
                                        <td align="right" style="background-color: #FFF;">3.50</td>
                                </tr>  <tr>
                                        <td style="background-color: #FAFAFA; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: clip;">Business Standard</td>
                                        <td align="right" style="background-color: #FAFAFA;">1,000</td>
                                        <td align="right" style="background-color: #FAFAFA;">2.20</td>
                                </tr>  <tr>
                                        <td style="background-color: #FFF; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: clip;">Business Professional</td>
                                        <td align="right" style="background-color: #FFF;">10,000</td>
                                        <td align="right" style="background-color: #FFF;">2.00</td>
                                </tr>  <tr>
                                        <td style="background-color: #FAFAFA; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: clip;">Business Premium</td>
                                        <td align="right" style="background-color: #FAFAFA;">50,000</td>
                                        <td align="right" style="background-color: #FAFAFA;">1.85</td>
                                </tr>  </table>
                </div>
                <div style="margin: 30px 0;">
                        Specify sms volume in the space below to get pricing <br />
                        <div>
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"
                                        id="aH">
                                        <tr>
                                                <th width="80">Volume</th>
                                                <th width="">Bundle</th>
                                                <th width="80" align="right">Unit Price</th>
                                                <th width="" align="right">Price</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                                <td bgcolor="#FEFEFE"><input name="df" type="text" value=""
                                                        size="10" maxlength="10" onkeyup="dJ()" /></td>
                                                <td bgcolor="#FEFEFE"><div id="J">
                                                                &nbsp; <input name="J" type="hidden" id="J" value="" />
                                                        </div></td>
                                                <td align="right"><div id="hBp">
                                                                &nbsp; <input name="hBp" type="hidden" id="hBp" value="" />
                                                        </div></td>
                                                <td align="right"><div id="T"><a name="how_to_recharge"></a>
                                                                &nbsp; <input name="T" type="hidden" id="T" value="" />
                                                        </div></td>
                                        </tr>
                                </table>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </form>
        IMPORTANT: *<strong>Business Premium bundle</strong> is the only <span
                style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">negotiable</span> bundle.
</div><div align="left" style="margin: 50px 0 0;">
        <h2>How to Recharge</h2>
        <p>Pay online with any Nigerian debit/credit card, or at any branch of the listed banks:</p>
                <div>
                <img alt="web payment" src="http://www.bbnplace.com/checkout/image/webpaymentgateways.gif" height="55" />
                </div>
                <div style="font-size: 14px;">
                        Account Name: <b>Browser Based Nigeria</b>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both; width: 100%;">
                        <div id="bM" align="center">
                                <img src="http://www.bbnplace.com/sms/media/images/zenith.jpeg"
                                        alt="Zenith Bank" width="50" height="50" /><br />1012259075
                        </div>
                        <div id="bM" align="center">
                                <img src="http://www.bbnplace.com/sms/media/images/gtblogo.gif"
                                        alt="Guaranty Trust Bank" width="50" height="50" /><br />0008382123
                        </div>
                        <div id="bM" align="center">
                                <img src="http://www.bbnplace.com/sms/media/images/diamondbank.jpg"
                                        alt="Diamond Bank Plc" width="50" height="50" /><br />0010549507
                        </div>
                        <div id="ibM" align="center">
                                <img src="http://www.bbnplace.com/sms/media/images/accessbank_logo.png"
                                        alt="Access Bank Plc" height="30" style="padding: 5px 0;" /><br />0049632011</div>
                </div>
        </div></div></div>
        <div id="form_pane">
                <div id="form_panel"><div align="left" id="signup">
<form name="signup_init" method="post" onsubmit = "return false;" autocomplete="off">
  <div align="right"><h2>Get Started!</h2></div>
        <div id="signup_init_error_message"></div>
      <div><b>Email</b></div>
      <div>
      <input name="new_user_email" type="email" id="new_user_email" onkeypress="quickSubmit(event, 'signup_init', 'signup_init_error_message')" title="Type Email" size="45" style="width:100%" />
      <span style="display: none;">User Email</span>
      </div>
      <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="validemail" value="0" />
      <input type="hidden" name="bservice" value="prepaidsms" />
      <input type="button" name="button2" id="aC" value="Sign Up" onclick="processFrm('signup_init', 'signup_init_error_message');" />
      </div>
</form>
</div></div>
                <div id="forms_seperator">OR</div>
                <div id="form_panel"><div>
<form name="blogin" method="post" onsubmit="return false;" autocomplete="off">
<div align="right"> <h2>Login</h2> </div>
<div id="errormsg"></div>
<div align="left">Email<br />
<label for="username"></label>
  <input type="email" name="busername" id="busername" class="frmfield" value="" onkeypress="quickSubmit(event, 'blogin', 'errormsg')" title="This should be your email" />
</div>
<div align="left">Password<br />
  <input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd" class="frmfield" value="" onkeypress="quickSubmit(event, 'blogin', 'errormsg')" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="hidden" name="bservice" id="bservice" value="prepaidsms" />
    <input type="hidden" name="returnto" id="returnto" value="http://sms.bbnplace.com/sentdir.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="errordiv" id="errordiv" value="errormsg" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ipaddress" id="ipaddress" value="41.58.242.131" />
</div>
<div align="left">
  <label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="1"  /> Remember Me!</label>
  <input type="button" name="button" id="button" class="K" value="Login" onclick="processFrm('blogin','errormsg')" />
</div>
<div style="padding: 5px 0;"><a href="http://www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2?do=login_failure&service=prepaidsms&returnto=http://sms.bbnplace.com/sentdir.php">Can't access my account</a></div>
</form>
</div></div>


                <div style="margin: 18px 0;">
                        <div style="margin: 0 0 5px;">Join our social conversation</div>
                        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/bbnsms"
                                data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="250"
                                data-show-faces="false"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div></div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div><div id="statsbar"></div>
</div>
<div id="aj" align="center"></div>
<div align="center" id="bn">
        <a href="//bs.bbnplace.com" title="Business Solutions">Business
                Solutions</a> | <a href="//dev.bbnplace.com">Developers</a> | <a
                href="//www.bbnplace.com/documentation">Documentation</a>
        | <a href="//newsroom.bbnplace.com">Newsroom</a>
        | <a href="//bbnplace.wordpress.com">Blog</a> | <a
                href="//www.bbnplace.com?entry=contact" target="_blank">Contact
                Us</a> <a href="//twitter.com/bbnplace" title="on Twitter"
                target="_blank"><img src="//www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2/style/twitter.png" alt="on Twitter"
                width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a> <a
                href="//www.facebook.com/bbnplace" title="on Facebook"
                target="_blank"><img src="//www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2/style/facebook.png" alt="on Facebook"
                width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a> <a
                href="//www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=4620527" title="at LinkedIn"
                target="_blank"><img src="//www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2/style/linkedin.png" alt="at LinkedIn"
                width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a> <a
                href="//www.youtube.com/user/bbnplace" title="on Youtube"
                target="_blank"><img src="//www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2/style/youtube.png" alt="on Youtube"
                width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a> <a
                href="//newsroom.bbnplace.com" title="at the Newsroom"
                target="_blank"><img src="//www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2/style/radio.png" alt="Newsroom" width="16"
                height="16" border="0" /></a>
                <br /> Copyright &copy; 2008 - 2016 <a
                href="//www.bbnplace.com" title="Browser Based Network Ltd">Browser
                Based Network Ltd</a>. <img src="//www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2/style/ngr.png" align="absmiddle"
                alt="Nigeria" /> Nigeria. All rights reserved.
                <br /><a href="//docs.bbnplace.com/?article=legals" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a> &bull; <a href="//docs.bbnplace.com/?article=privacy_policy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy Statement</a>
                <br /> <b>Desktop | <a
                href="//m.sms.bbnplace.com">Mobile</a> Edition
        </b>
</div>
<div
        style="float: right; position: fixed; z-index: 100000; top: 230px; right: 0px;">
        <img src="//www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2/style/feedback_button.png" onclick="bB()"
                style="cursor: pointer;" />
</div><div id="t">
        <div id="j">
                <form name="t" action="return false;" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="an" value="Mobile Messaging Solutions" />
                        <h1 style="color: #555;">Send Us Feedback</h1>
                        <div>If you notice something is not working properly or you have a
                                suggestions. We appreciate hearing from you</div>
                        <div id="V"></div>
                        <div>
                                <b>Full Name:</b><br /> <input type="text" name="ag"
                                        style="width: 95%;" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                                <b>Email:</b><br /> <input type="text" name="bI" style="width: 95%;" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                                <b>Phone:</b> <i>(optional)</i><br /> <input type="text" name="aR"
                                        style="width: 200px;" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                                <b>Suggestion:</b><br />
                                <textarea name="av" rows="10"
                                        style="width: 95%; min-width: 95%; max-width: 95%; height: 100px; max-height: 100px;"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                                Read our <a href="http://docs.bbnplace.com/?article=privacy_policy"
                                        target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> statement
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin: 10px 0 0;">
                                <span id="aC" onclick="aN()">Submit Feedback</span> <span class="K"
                                        onclick="ar()">Cancel</span>
                        </div>
                </form>
        </div>
        <div id="h">
                <div id="bv">
                        <img src="style/correct_marking.gif" align="absmiddle" /> Your
                        feedback has been received. Thank you for the time taken
                </div>
                <div style="margin: 50px 0 0;">
                        <span class="K" onclick="ar()">Close</span>
                </div>
        </div>
</div><div id="cs"><div style="text-align:center;white-space:nowrap;"> <div><a href="http://livechat.boldchat.com/aid/4518259610467392165/bc.chat?cwdid=2945491719484839364" target="_blank" onclick="window.open((window.cl&&cl.link||function(link){return link;})(this.href+(this.href.indexOf('?')>=0?'&amp;':'?')+'url='+escape(document.location.href)),'Chat1609025529230970721','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=520,height=360,left=190,top=250');return false;"><img alt="Live chat" src="https://cbi.boldchat.com/aid/4518259610467392165/bc.cbi?cbdid=6794783422064795815" border="0"/></a></div></div></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: The "logged in" state of a browser is based on its Cookie header. The server sets it to a value after a successful login via the Set-Cookie header, make sure to follow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to post to the correct url, once successfully logged in you will be able to get whatever page you like, this is a working example using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


post = "http://www.bbnplace.com/accounts_v2/source/loginp.php"
data = {"eml": "your_email",
        "p": "your_pass"}

# use a Session to persist cookies.
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post(post, data=data) # log us in 
    print(r.content) # will output "successful" for correct login 
    r = s.get("http://sms.bbnplace.com/account.php") # get account page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    print(soup.title.text)
```

Comment: Gee Thanks, I would have just kept going around in circles.