# How to Login to a website using beautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I am very new to Python, I am trying to extract data from a site.
For that I am stuck on the first step of Login into the site only.

This is what I have tried:

```
#Importing Libs
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import http

jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar(policy=None)

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

#Setting account details
acc_pwd = {'user_username':'userABC',
           'user_password':'ABC123'}
#enter URL           
quote_page = 'example.com'
response = http.request('GET', quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data)

print ("Data %s" % soup)

r = requests.get(quote_page, cookies=jar)
r = requests.post(quote_page, cookies=jar, data=acc_pwd)

print ("##############")
print ("RData %s" % r.text)
```

It takes me back to login page only.
Not sure if i am entering the details properly or not.

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102833/how-to-scrape-a-website-which-requires-login-using-python-and-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

this generally works for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests import Request, Session
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth 

base_url = ''
r = requests.get(base_url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username', 'password'))
```