# Can't find span tag on quora website using beautifulsoup search by class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, quora

I am using beautifulsoup to parse quora urls and retrive upvotes counts for each answer, by looking for  tags containing "icon_action_bar-count" Class. The problem is that the result is always empty or 'None' despite that the class can be found manually in the original page (using mozilla developer interface),

I am using this simple beautifulsoup command:

```
upvote =soup.findAll("span",{"class":"icon_action_bar-count"})
```

below the html span tag i am trying to retrieve,and the quora url containg this html code:

```
<span class="icon_action_bar-count" id="__w2_bgylC4B_count_wrapper">
  <span class="bullet"> · </span>
  <span id="__w2_bgylC4B_count">610</span>
</span>
```

https://www.quora.com/Why-do-a-lot-of-rich-people-say-rent-instead-of-buy-property

Answer (score 0):

That span element is only within the HTML of the page for a signed in user. If its not found when searching then likely you are not signed in to the site.

Comment: any idea how to resolve this problem in python? cause when i open the url manually using both chrome and Mozilla browsers, i am automatically signed in.

Comment: Youcef, I would check out this article, you will need some method of logging into the web page via Python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102833/how-to-scrape-a-website-which-requires-login-using-python-and-beautifulsoup