# Unable to Login with Python Requests - Unknown Error

Tags: python, html, authentication, python-requests

Im trying to login and scrape data using beautiful soup and requests with python on this website: https://wehner.myresman.com/Access/SignIn but when I do a `requests.post` with my login info it gives me an error.

```
import requests
import login

payload = {'Username':'Username', 'Password': 'Password'}

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}


with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://wehner.myresman.com/Access/SignIn'
    r = s.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())
```

The error message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Error
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   Whoops!  Something went wrong!  We apologize for the inconvenience. (id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its seems to me that it is a server side problem.

Comment: Try to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102833/how-to-scrape-a-website-which-requires-login-using-python-and-beautifulsoup