# Not able to scrape "link-text" using python

Tags: python

Not able to scrape the link-text using python, there is no output provided.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 URL='https://pro.imdb.com/companies? 
 ref_=hm_nv_co_pr#companyType=production&sort=ranking&pos=0&page=1'
 headers={"User Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
 Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}


 def Extract_prod_companies():
   page=requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
   soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html5lib')

   for tag in soup.find_all('a',{"class":"display-company"}):
      print(tag.text)    
 Extract_prod_companies()
```

Comment: Hello, can you paste an example of the tag you are searching for (with its attributes and text) in your question?

Comment: [How to scrape a website which requires login using python and beautifulsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23102833) maybe.

Comment: @DannyStaple <a href="https://pro.imdb.com/company/co0726862/?ref_=search_company_result_1">Kreativ Artists</a>

Comment: Can you put that in backticks '`', in the answer, so it's formatted please? It didn't seem to come out correctly there.

Comment: The url probably needs authentication before listing the results you want. Whn I (or bs4) go to the page I just see a landing page to buy IMDB pro.