# How to print the first google search result link using bs4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner in python, I'm trying to get the first search result link from google which was stored inside a div with class='yuRUbf' using beautifulsoup. When I run the script output is 'None' what is the error here.

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+how+to+use+bs4+in+python&sxsrf=AOaemvKrCLt-Ji_EiPLjcEso3DVfBUmRbg%3A1630215433722&ei=CR0rYby7K7ue4-EP7pqIkAw&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+how+to+use+bs4+in+python&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgjELACECc6BQgAEM0CSgQIQRgAUMw2WPh_YLiFAWgBcAJ4AIABkAKIAd8lkgEHMC4xMC4xM5gBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj849XewdXyAhU7zzgGHW4NAsIQ4dUDCA8&uact=5'

request_result=requests.get( url )
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request_result.text,"html.parser")
productDivs = soup.find("div", {"class": "yuRUbf"})
print(productDivs)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want first google search in which class name which you are looking for might be differ with name so first you can first find manually that link so it will be easy to identify

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+how+to+use+bs4+in+python&sxsrf=AOaemvKrCLt-Ji_EiPLjcEso3DVfBUmRbg%3A1630215433722&ei=CR0rYby7K7ue4-EP7pqIkAw&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+how+to+use+bs4+in+python&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgjELACECc6BQgAEM0CSgQIQRgAUMw2WPh_YLiFAWgBcAJ4AIABkAKIAd8lkgEHMC4xMC4xM5gBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj849XewdXyAhU7zzgGHW4NAsIQ4dUDCA8&uact=5'

request_result=requests.get( url )

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request_result.text,"html.parser")
```

**Using `select` method:**

> 1. I have used css selector method in which it identifies all matching
>    divs and from list i have taken from index postion 1
> 2. And than i have use `select_one` to get `a` tag and find `href`
>    according to it!

```
main_data=soup.select("div.ZINbbc.xpd.O9g5cc.uUPGi")[1:]
main_data[0].select_one("a")['href'].replace("/url?q=","")
```

**Using `find` method:**

```
main_data=soup.find_all("div",class_="ZINbbc xpd O9g5cc uUPGi")[1:]
main_data[0].find("a")['href'].replace("/url?q=","")
```

**Output [Same for Both the Case]:**

```
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102833/how-to-scrape-a-website-which-requires-login-using-python-and-beautifulsoup&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjGxv2wytXyAhUprZUCHR8mBNsQFnoECAkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw280R9Wlz2mUKHFYQUOFVv8'
```

Comment: Find method works well but when I change the "url" again the output is invalid

Comment: beacuse the class name may be differ from that so it will not be always same class name

Comment: then what is solution that works with all url? when I inspect I get the same class on all page 'class="yuRUbf"

Comment: can you share URL again please for reference

Comment: here it is: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+how+to+use+bs4+in+python&oq=&aqs=chrome.0.69i59i450l8.92637j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: it is working i have checked with above URL

Comment: can you please check with this one: https://www.google.com/search?q=cars&oq=cars&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i61j69i60l2.3087j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Yes correct for above car URL it is identifies divs but problem is that URL containing in first index is not same as from Web page in that case you can use try and except block to first call URL from and if status_code is not 200 then you can go for next index

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "useragent"
}


html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=hello', headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
# locating div element with a tF2Cxc class
# calling for <a> tag and then calling for 'href' attribute
link = soup.find('div', class_='tF2Cxc').a['href']
print(link)
```

## output:

'''
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A