# Programmatically Provide Secondary WiFi HotSpot Credentials with Python on Linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, urllib2, mechanize-python

I have credentials for a WiFi Service that is "Open" in the sense that in order to associate with it, a user is not required to provide a password. There is a secondary authentication method required to actually access the internet, and in order to do this I must enter my credentials through the browser as shown in the screen grab below:

[image]

Since I am on Linux, I'd like to be able to provide my credentials programmatically with Python. Most examples I've seen ( e.g. [How to programmatically log into website in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516527/how-to-programmatically-log-into-website-in-python) ), desire the 'name of the form'. I cannot see this information when viewing 'Page Source' in the browser and I'm not sure how to properly submit my credentials automatically. I would greatly appreciate some help on this! Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Here is an example I tried -

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cookielib 
import urllib2 
import mechanize 

# Browser 
br = mechanize.Browser() 

# Enable cookie support for urllib2 
cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar() 
br.set_cookiejar( cookiejar ) 

# Broser options 
br.set_handle_equiv( True ) 
br.set_handle_gzip( True ) 
br.set_handle_redirect( True ) 
br.set_handle_referer( True ) 
br.set_handle_robots( False ) 

# ?? 
br.set_handle_refresh( mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time = 1 ) 

br.addheaders = [ ( 'User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1' ) ] 

# authenticate 
br.open( "http://www.google.com" ) 
br.select_form( name="Authentication Required" ) 
# these two come from the code you posted
# where you would normally put in your username and password
br[ "USERID" ] = my_user
br[ "PASSWDTXT" ] = my_pass
res = br.submit() 

print "Success!\n"
```

The problem is that I just receive this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./login.py", line 29, in <module>
    br.open( "http://www.google.com" ) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
    raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

UPDATE 2: I also tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2

username = my_user
password = my_pass

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://%s:%s@google.com'%(username,password)})
auth = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy, auth, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

conn = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
return_str = conn.read()
```

But the error is the same:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./login.py", line 13, in <module>
    conn = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you're requesting replied with a 401 HTTP response code (access denied), and your Web browser is showing a HTTP Basic Authentication ([RFC  2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617)) dialog to retry the request with credentials.

Your second example is partway there, but you're not supplying a username or password to the password manager (`auth`, created by `HTTPBasicAuthHandler`). Try something like this instead (Python 2.7):

```
import urllib2

url = "http://www.example.com"
username = "bob"
password = "pass123"

# Create a password manager with your password(s)
password_store = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_store.add_password(None, url, username, password)
passwords = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_store)

# Open the URL with password(s) with `opener`
opener = urllib2.build_opener(passwords)
resp = opener.open(url)
resp.read()
```