# Navigating webpages with python/javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, browser

I'm working on a program that requires information from some webpages. Currently, I'm getting info by just downloading the source and parsing it (in Python with Regex). However, there's more specific/better data I could be using, but it requires a login and some page navigation by the "user". (The pages with the data can't just be reached by typing in the URL)

I can write javascript/jquery to simulate the logging in and clicking that's needed to navigate to these pages..but currently I can only "run" it by siting in chrome and pulling up the chrome javascript console on each page. Is there a way to simulate browser navigation purely in Python, so I could automate this task? (Also, the page doesn't appear to have any sort of captcha or anti-bot security, o that shouldn't be a problem)

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spynner

Comment: Better you can try **Urllib2**. Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925983/login-to-website-using-urllib2-python-2-7.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out some browser automation tools, for example [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org). It's used for website testing primarily, but you can also extract information with it, and then process it in python.

Here is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540971/how-to-use-selenium-with-python), about using it from python.

Comment: Some response would have been nice.