# What is the use of cookiejar in getting url

Tags: python, urllib, cookiejar

I would like to implement what is shown here:

[Login to website using urllib2 - Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925983/login-to-website-using-urllib2-python-2-7)

My question is why is cookielib and cookiejar needed in the code? Why will the code not work without cookielib and cookiejar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you log in to a website, they usually give you a "cookie". When you load another page from the same site, you can show them this cookie to let them know who you are.

The cookie jar is a data structure that manages this for you.

Without it, you could not stay logged in.