# Python: how to use urllib to stay logged into website over an entire session

Tags: python, authentication, urllib

I'm having trouble *staying* logged into a website using python. I found this question ([Login to website using urllib2 - Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925983/login-to-website-using-urllib2-python-2-7)) for python2, which I updated to python3 changing cookieLib to http.cookiejar and urllib2 to urllib.request (among other updates). It seems to log me in, but when I reopen the page with urlopen, I'm not logged in. There was a similar comment to this on the question but it went unanswered. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you use requests instead? A requests Session object handles all this for you

Comment: have you tried release_conn = False (https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/index.html#module-urllib3.connectionpool) Also, if you are not tied to urllib, you might find requests easier - specifically using Sessions (https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)

Comment: Tried requests, and its much less complicated and insofar, works! Thanks!